# How can I add " " to each item in this collection in RoR?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, collections

At the moment, I have this run of code:

```
<%=h current_user.notes.collect { |t| t.name }.join(', ') %>
```

which outputs this:

```
note 1, note 2, note 3
```

How can I change it so that the output looks like this?

```
"note 1", "note 2", "note 3"
```

Thanks for reading.

Edit: Here is the full code of KandadaBoggu's suggestion below

```
$(window).ready(function() {
    $("input#note_name").autocomplete({
        source: [<%=h escape_javascript(current_user.notes.collect { |t| '"%s"' % t.name }.join(', ')) %>]
    });
});
```

And here is the output HTML:

```
$(window).ready(function() {
    $("input#note_name").autocomplete({
        source: [\&quot;note 1\&quot;, \&quot;note 2\&quot;]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
current_user.notes.collect { |t| '"%s"' % t.name }.join(', ')
```

You can escape the string for javascript:

```
escape_javascript(current_user.notes.collect { |t| '"%s"' % t.name }.join(', '))
```

**Note**
If you test the code in a `irb` console it will print the following output:

```
"\"note 1\", \"note 2\", \"note 3\""
```

This is the correct result as the irb console escapes the quotes. The string will be displayed without the `\` in a view

Comment: Hmm, strange that it works in the console but not in my view. This is my output: &quot;note 1&quot;, &quot;note 2&quot;

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I'm running this code in javascript, not sure if that makes a difference?

Comment: It should not. Use `escape_javascript` and see if it makes any difference. Refer to my updated answer.

Comment: Didn't work again. I've posted the full code and output HTML above. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Go it working, just had to remove the h from <%=h
Thanks again.